# If $R$ is a ring and $a,b \in R$. Show that $a(-b)+2a\cdot2b=3ab$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Assume that $R$ is a ring and $a,b \in R$. Show that $$a(-b)+2a\cdot2b=3ab.$$ Keep an eye for what definitions of a ring you use in each step.

I'm trying to learn about rings from a book on algebraic structures and there's a few definitions on the operations. I have that $a(-b)=-(ab)$ so $$a(-b)+2a\cdot2b=-(ab)+2a\cdot2b.$$

It's tempting to group the last two terms as $4ab$, but I feel like there is some catch here that I'm not seeing? This would result in $$-(ab)+4ab=3ab$$ that seems to be working according to the definitions of  a ring?

Comment: For $x \in R$ and $n \in \mathbb Z^+$, the symbol $nx$ is a notation for $\underbrace{x+\cdots+x}_{n \rm{\, times}}$. Use the distributivity of the product over the sum to show that $(a+a)(b+b) = ab+ab+ab+ab+ab$

Comment: Everything is right, but if this is immediately after the definition of "ring" is given, then you're making too many assumptions.  This type of problem is to check that your intuition you've built up studying math still works in this broader context, so you should check everything (e.g. some students think $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ in a general ring without realizing it requires $ab=ba$ which may not be true)

Comment: What you have done is basically what you're supposed to do. But you're supposed to be super detailed about the justification for every single step.

Comment: One "catch": does your proof still work when you replace $2b$ by $cb$ for arbitrary $c$ (which may not commute with $a$)? If not, then you proof should include a remark  justifying why the pertinent step is true when $\,c = 2.\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going purely by the definition of a ring we get the following:
$$\begin{align}
a(-b)+2a\cdot2b &= a(-b)+(a+a)(b+b) \tag{definition}\\
&=a(-b)+a(b+b)+a(b+b) \tag{right distributivity}\\
&=a(-b)+ab+ab+ab+ab \tag{left distributivity}\\
&=a((-b)+b)+ab+ab+ab \tag{left distributivity}\\
&=a(0)+ab+ab+ab \tag{additive inverse}\\
&=a(0+b)+ab+ab \tag{left distributivity}\\
&=ab+ab+ab \tag{additive identity}\\
&=3ab \tag{definition}
\end{align}$$
It's a bit excessive, but does purely rely on the basic axioms and definitions.

Comment: I know you say it's "excessive" but imagine if you included all of the instances of the associative property at work in this computation! :-)